# Unexpected T String

Tags: php

I get an error in this code so it will not run on my PC. When I put it into a code checker I am told there is an error that is an unexpected T String. However, I tried to look at ways of solving this including surrounding different parts of the code in quote marks but this makes no difference.

In particular it is the "If" statement for the e-mail address field being empty. One code checker even told me the word 'Enter' was unexpected.

```
<?php

function load( $page = 'login.php' )

{

$url = 'http://' . $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] .
               dirname( $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ] ) ;

$url = rtrim( $url , '^\' ) ;

$url .= '/' . $page ;

header( "Location: $url" ) ;
exit() ;


function validate( $dbc , $email = " , $pwd = " )

{

$errors = array() ;

if ( empty( $email ) )
{ $errors[] = 'Enter your email address.' ; }
else { $e = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $email ) ) ; }

if ( empty( $pwd ) )
{ $errors[] = 'Enter your password.' ; }
else { $p = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, trim( $pwd ) ) ; }

if ( empty( $errors ))
{
$q = "SELECT user_id, first_name, last_name, 
   FROM users
   WHERE email = '$e'
   AND pass = SHA1( '$p' ) " ;

$r = mysqli_query ( $dbc , $q ) ;

if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 )
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_array ( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ;
return array( true , $row ) ;
}
else

{ $errors[] = 'Email address and password not found.' ; } 

}

return array( false , $errors ) ;  }



}


?>
```

Comment: Go and read about `PHP` and `escaping`. Then fix that.

Answer (score 2):

In the following line of code:

```
$url = rtrim( $url , '^\' ) ;
```

You have actually escaped the closing `'` by putting a `\` in front of it. This has caused the rest of your code to be assumed as a continuation of the string you are trying to define.

You should replace it with a double `\\` which actually escapes the first backslash, thereby defining the string as you meant:

```
$url = rtrim( $url , '^\\' ) ;
```

Comment: Also as @alfasin points out, there are further errors (missing brackets) that you will need to look into.

Answer (score 0):

1. The load function is missing a closing bracket: }
2. `function validate( $dbc , $email = " , $pwd = " )` - you probably meant to write: `function validate( $dbc , $email = "" , $pwd = "" )` or: 
   `function validate( $dbc , $email = '' , $pwd = '' )`- the way you posted your code it cannot run!
3. After calling `header( "Location...` don't `exit() ;` - use `return`
4. You are checking if email/pwd are empty and save the errors but you don't change the flow of the program: you shouldn't call the DB at all in such case - but rather display the error immediately!
5. A better practice will be to use [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) instead of string concatenation inside the query -  `mysqli_real_escape_string` *[is NOT bullet proof against sql-injection](http://www.larryullman.com/2012/09/07/sql-injection-and-mysqli_real_escape_string/)*
6. And this one is personal "taste": when you post a question on SO try to ident the code and make it readable, further, to do something like `else {blablabla..... ;}` in the same line - does not follow any of the code conventions, try to embrace one code convention and stick to it!

Comment: Thanks to all you guys for the help and the effort of making detailed replies. I am not convinced I am cut out for PHP but some of the errors are clearly a result of the book I am using which is unclear. Thank God I am nearly finished with this book.